# Why does my Android app keep telling me I need to define a ListView id when it is already defined?

Tags: android, listview

Whenever I try to run my app, the following exception is thrown:

01-22 00:40:51.868: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2219): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{[Redacted]}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Here is the markup for the ListView in question:

```
<ListView 
 android:id="@+id/list" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:dividerHeight="1px"></ListView>
```

So, since the id is clearly defined as "list," what gives here? I've run through my code multiple times in the past couple of hours trying to track down the cause of this and I'm stumped. Can anyone offer any pointers?

Comment: can you pls paste code of xml whr you define listview and code of jave file whr u get tht id.

Answer (score 5):

Probably your class `ComponentInfo` is extending the `ListActivity` therefore insure that your `ListView` object must have the following attribute in your layout XML file:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is a difference between "android.R.id.list" and simply "R.id.list"

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" />
```

is not the same list as

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" />
```

The first one has a predefined id in the android framework which means that some things are made automatically in the background for you. Consider the example below:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:width="match_parent"
        android:height="match_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list" />

    <TextView
        android:width="wrap_content"
        android:height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:text="You don\'t have any items yet." />
</LinearLayout>
```

Given the above layout in your XML and that your corresponding java class extends the ListActivity, the TextView will automatically be shown for you when your list doesn't have any items and it will also automatically be hidden when the list get its first item.

Comment: if you test you're actual xml you'll realize that it's in fact @namespace:name/ressource -> "@android:id/list". You should edit your answer and fix all @id/android: . That's wrong

Comment: Well, actually according to this resource my XML markup seems correct: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Comment: Well that's strange because I never seen that syntax and if you look above in the doc it write @android:id/list.

Comment: @Loïc Faure-Lacroix: I have now tested the code example "IRL" and both id-conventions seems to result in the desired behaviour. However, when using Eclipse with ADT-plugin only the "@android:id/list" and "@android:id/empty" seems to be "suggested" by the IDE. You're also right in your statement about how an id is built up (@[namespace]:[name]/[resource]), hence I realize that your suggested id-convention is the more proper way to write it, regardless of personal preferences and empirical testing of which one works and which doesn't. I have changed my example code.

Comment: Well the Android api has a lots of strange things. And the documentation doesn't really help about that in most case.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have accidentl imported android.R package.

remove the import and you should do fine.

Answer (score -1):

hi Todd
whatever u give listview's id in XML 
thst id u want to declare in java class.

sample code in XML

    
 & In java class

ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);