# How do I define the list for my ListActivity?

Tags: java, android, listactivity

I have a list activity using a layout that has more than just the listview in it. It also has a button and a spinner. I receive the error that says I need to have a listview widget named 'list'.

10-15 23:28:36.131: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(448): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{rams.rss/rams.rss.RamsRSS}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

However, it already has a listview object named list. I used one solution from here:

[Why does my Android app keep telling me I need to define a ListView id when it is already defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766977/why-does-my-android-app-keep-telling-me-i-need-to-define-a-listview-id-when-it-i)

It only caused another error in which a copy with the .out suffix is added.

rams_layout.xml -> rams_layout.out.xml

Here is the contents of the xml file I'm using:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button android:text="Back" android:layout_width="wrap_content"         android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"         android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></Button>
        <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner1"         android:layout_width="wrap_content"         android:layout_height="wrap_content"         android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></Spinner>
        <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="match_parent"         android:layout_height="wrap_content"         android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Can post post the code for the onCreate method in your Activity?

Comment: Can explain the error you have exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project. In Eclipse, this is Project|Clean from the main menu. From the command line, this is `ant clean`.

> It only caused another error in which a copy with the .out suffix is added. rams_layout.xml -> rams_layout.out.xml

Most likely, that is because you attempted to run an Android project while having an XML file as the active tab in the editor. I thought this problem was fixed -- make sure you are on the latest version of the ADT plugin for Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I noticed - your ListView's ID is formatted in an interesting manner. Try changing its android:id to:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" ...
```

I have an Activity with the same setup and this is how I reference my ListView:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setAdapter(...
```